# Text cursor bug in my Chrome browser that causes the blinking cursor to appear everywhere I click

Tags: google-chrome

There is a text cursor bug in my chrome that causes the blinking cursor to appear everywhere I click

There is an annoying bug in my chrome that causes a blinking cursor also known as "the text cursor," or "the insertion point" to appear wherever I click. For those guys who don't know what it is, it's the cursor that appears when you click on an element that you can edit on any website (like the comments section on youtube).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found solution

There's an options called "**Navigate pages with a text cursor**" in **Accessibility settings**, you'll need to disable this option.

> Chrome Settings ​​--> Advanced --> Accessibility.
>
> Or Press **F7** Key

Comment: Guessing my kid pressed F7 then - Holy crap that has been harrassing me for weeks!

Answer (score 2):

Like Abdo-Host said, it's a setting called "Navigate pages with a text cursor".

Also good to know: The standard short-key for enabling and disabling this "feature" is **F7**.